# SQL pivot rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a query that returns two types by agency "Vente" and "Recouv". I want that my request displays one line with the sum of the column "Commission".

Here is a picture that shows what I have and what I want:

```
 select codeAgence,CASE WHEN (TypeOperation =0) THEN 'Vente' ELSE 'Recouvrement' END  as 'Type',
 count(*) 'Nb',SUM(PxVenteHT ) 'C.A',SUM(acompte) 'Montant',SUM(MontantCommission ) 'Commission' from Commission_Archive
  group by CodeAgence,TypeOperation
  order by CodeAgence
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might do what you want, but as your question lacks proper sample source data I haven't tested it.

```
SELECT 
    codeAgence,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (TypeOperation = 0) THEN 'Vente' ELSE NULL END) 'Nb Vente',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (TypeOperation = 0) THEN PxVenteHT ELSE 0 END) 'C.A',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (TypeOperation <> 0) THEN 'Recouve' ELSE NULL END) 'Nb Recouve',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (TypeOperation <> 0) THEN acompte ELSE 0 END) 'Montant Recouve',
    SUM(MontantCommission) 'Commission' 
FROM Commission_Archive 
GROUP BY CodeAgence
ORDER BY CodeAgence
```

The key is to apply the conditional aggregation technique to all the aggregated columns that should be split on Nb/Recouve and change the grouping.